# Google Apps Script set relative height attribute

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I want to have an image with a relative size in relation to the screen. I can manually set a specific amount and I can get the width to auto-fit; however, no luck with height. I'm simply wanting to make the height equal to the width (also without simply altering the image file to be equal) in JavaScript and it seems like there's a restriction for some reason. Does anyone know what will work with Google Apps Script or is this currently impossible?

The code will be a web app inputted in an HTML file returned using the HtmlService. Everything else works and I'm able to edit the height in a plain HTML file, just not in GAS.

To test, I've used the base HTML (the image was just taken from a quick google search as an example):

```
<style>img{width:40%}</style>
<img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/img15/pet-products/small-tiles/23695_pets_vertical_store_dogs_small_tile_8._CB312176604_.jpg" />
```

Then the Javascript:

```
<script>
var img=document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for(var i=0;i<img.length;i++){img[i].style.height = img[i].width};
</script>
```

and

```
<script>
var img=document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for(var i=0;i<img.length;i++){img[i].style.height = img[i].style.width};
</script>
```

Comment: In a webapp, a dialog, a sidebar? Are you batch resizing images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out...was simply:
img[i].height=img[i].width
GAS wouldn't accept it through style.